# broken classpath with Intellij Idea on maven dependency

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, nexus, build-numbers

i'm using Intellij IDEA 12.1.6, almost everyone in my company use Eclipse and dont notice my problem. We have a local nexus repository where we deploy artifacts, but some of them are systematically created with an invalid maven-metadata.xml (the latest snapshot timestamp and build number does not match the effective artifact name on repo) and intellij ends up telling me those libraries have broken classpath.

Is there a way to force intellij on hooking the maven jars on my local repository without worrying about those metadata additional information? Eg eclipse hook the jar in his classpath taking the version which does not include those data (in my m2 repo dir i see both 2 jars downloaded, the one with full data and the other one without them)
eg.

library-0.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
 library-0.0.6-SNAPSHOT-20131028.111135-10.jar

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The best fix would be to get the metadata fixed. There is a scheduled task in Nexus that can do that.

Comment: if i could do it, there would be no reason to ask this question. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

If Importing the [eclipse project did not work](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-eclipse-projects-into-intellij-idea.html). You should be able to [Configure the library contents](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html#d1123704e589) . The step for [Configure Library Dialog](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configure-library-dialog.html) should allow you to point the library to a different location.

Comment: thank you for the answer, anyway the last intellij update did solved the issue without manually touching libraries configuration.